# Limiting the number of active CPU cores with Numba

Tags: python, parallel-processing, numba

I'm trying to limit the number of active CPU cores when running a funtion with the decorator `@njit(parallel=True)` from the Numba library.

So far I've done something like this (example):

```
from numba import njit, prange, set_num_threads

import numpy as np


@njit(parallel=True)
def func():

    for i in prange(int(1e10)):

        print(np.cos(i))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    num_threads = input(f'Enter max number of threads to use: ')

    set_num_threads(int(num_threads))

    func()
```

but even when setting the number of threads to 1 a quick check with Task Manager shows that the workload is still being shared by all the cores (4 in my case).

In the following screenshot it is possible to see this. The red circles show the time of starting and interruption of the program.

[Task Manager Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYKKO.png)

Is there a better way of limiting the number of active cores?

Comment: Why do you want decidedly to limit _the number of active cores_ over the whole computation duration rather than limit the CPU utilization?

Answer (score 5):

You are stressing your cpu cores by using the print function and displaying them in the console, not because of the calculation. In this example I accumulate the values before printing only once. In this way, you can see more easily the real cpu usage of the code.

```
from numba import njit, prange, set_num_threads

import numpy as np


@njit(parallel=True)
def func():

    k = 0
    for i in prange(int(1e10)):
        k = k + np.cos(i)

    print(k)



if __name__ == '__main__':

    num_threads = input(f'Enter max number of threads to use: ')

    set_num_threads(int(num_threads))
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Shouldn't the stress caused by the print function only be present in the number of cores set by `set_num_threads`? I don't really have a problem with stressing the cores, so long as it only stresses the number of cores set.

Comment: @MiguelFerro, the user specific code of the print function yes, but the overhead you see in the task manager is most likely due to the rendering of the results in the command window, which it is outside of your python script.

Comment: I think that I understand what you're saying but even running your version of the code with `num_threads=2` it still seems that the workload is being shared through all the cores. https://imgur.com/ySaoYqm

Comment: @MiguelFerro In the system monitor you should look to the cpu usage of the process, not the overall system usage.